# Image based core graphics drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, drawing, core-graphics

I have to draw many shapes like rectangle, circle, triangle etc.I am drawing them trough core graphics.
It is working fine.
I want to ask suppose I am having an image (square image of say 1024*1024), and now I  want my circle to draw as image means like I draw red color circle or other color, so if it is possible to show my image as drawn in the circle, like the image is circle,

```
My code for normal circle  drawing:-
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [ [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, 0.7);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, radius, radius);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx, radius,radius, radius,  radians(0), radians(360), 0);
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

}
```

I want to draw my image as circle.

**Basically I want like we can fill colors in core graphics drawing whether circle, arc, triangle. so is that possible to fill my shape with my image instead of any solid colors.**

Is this possible and if yes please suggest me how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you want do draw the image? if your gol is to have a cirle image you can use myImageView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0

Comment: For circle it may be correct but if I want it in a triangle then?

Comment: so, you can add a white rectangle view on the image, and draw the triangle circle or any shape by delating pixel of the view

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate in coding tems.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia  Please check my edited question,I have made my question more clear.

Comment: try this out for setting color in `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` function `[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.jpg"]CGColor]`

Comment: @Wolvorin Please post this as a answer so that I can vote up and accept.

Comment: ok glade to know that this is working and help you out with your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out for setting color in `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` function `[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.jpg"]CGColor];`

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIView with and rectangular on the image.

In this view, you must draw the hole.

Now i not have the mac and i cannot check, but try to substitute

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [ [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]);
```

with

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(currentContext, kCGBlendModeClear);
```

let me know

Comment: sorry This is not want I need to implement.